# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+2)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I need to evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+2)!}$$Answer in book and WolframAlpha both say that is equal $3-e$. Thus, I have mistake and got:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+2)!}
&=0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+2)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+2)!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+2)-2}{(n+2)!}\\
&=-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\\
&= -2(e-1)=2-2e
\end{align}
$$

Please help to find mistake.

Comment: How did you get from $\frac{(n+2)-2}{(n+2)!}$ to $-2\cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$?

Comment: I think it should be $3 - e$, just some manual labour will yield it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+2-2}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+1)!}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+2)!}$$

$$=\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac1{r!}-2\sum_{u=3}^\infty\frac1{u!}$$

Now $e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}{r!}\implies e=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac1{r!}$

Comment: Thanks! As both sums convergent, I can evaluate them separate?

Comment: @EvgenyEgorov, Definitely

Answer (score 3):

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+2)!}=0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+2)!}=
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+2)!}= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+2)-2}{(n+2)!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-2\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)!}=e-1-2(e-1-\frac{1}{1!})=3-e$ As expected